# Cycle-by-cycle overcurrent protection

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, circuit-protection

I'm designing a gate driver for my SiC MOSFET [SCT3160KL](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/sic/mosfet/sct3160kl-e.pdf) using gate driver [UCC21732-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc21732-q1.pdf?ts=1602225776692&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC21732-Q1) from TI. I am using overcurrent protection, active Miller clamping, UVLO and also overvoltage protection by using a TVS diode between the Gate and Source of the switch.

I'd like to know if there is some rule governing the need of more levels of overcurrent protection. Like, say I want to add cycle-by-cycle overcurrent protection. From what I read, I understand this is mostly used in buck/boost converters, but I think I can implement it here for overcurrent protection.

My idea is to detect the current by the "AIN" pin of gate driver, but I'm not sure how to add the cycle-by-cycle part with counters etc. Any views pointing me in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: You should expand the question with details, schematics. It's not clear what s the function of  mentioned TVS, and these integrated over current protections are meant to switch off before it's too late, a certain amount of time is needed before reset and start agin, not for cycle protection.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I haven't added a schematic because I couldn't implement the cycle-by-cycle protection. I thought TVS or Zener diodes could be used for overvoltage protection of the MOSFET (it wouldn't be a part of the gate driver schematic of course).